# Call for contributors: Ask Different Screencasts!

Tags: discussion, blog

In the beginning, the Ask Different blog was only used to distribute podcast episodes.
Then we expanded to text articles.
Now we're expanding to videos.

As of today, the Ask Different blog has a [Vimeo account](http://vimeo.com/askdifferentblog) where we will be posting videos. We'll be starting with screencasts, and hopefully moving to other kinds of videos (hardware reviews, unboxings, iPhone release day footage, etc).

The first video has just been published. You can see it [here](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/keyboard-ninja-working-with-text-screencast/).

**If you're interested in contributing screencasts or have any questions, let me know!** Post an answer to this question or ping me in the [Blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1408/ask-different-blog).
Here's how the process works.

1. You, community member, create an awesome screencast of your Mac or iOS device (or other video).
2. You get in touch with me so we can transfer the video file via your
   preferred method.
3. I process the video, do any necessary editing, and add our fancy Ask
   Different Blog intro and outro.
4. You create a blog post with a short writeup for your video.
5. When the time comes, I upload the video and publish the blog post.

---

If you're interested in playing around or processing your own screencasts, you can download the template iMovie [project](http://cl.ly/0r3I210h2l3k2d1b1D22) and [event](http://cl.ly/3u462v3W3N0O150Y0V2E). Place the project in `~/Movies/iMovie Projects` and the event in `~/Movies/iMovie/iMovie Events`.

Comment: "In the beginning, Steve Woz and Jobs created the Apple I." And since then, a ton of stuff happened.

Comment: Actually, according to the biography they created phone phreaking hardware (Blue Boxes, I think?) before that.

Comment: @JasonSalaz Haven't read the biography yet, but it's on my list.

Comment: I'd tentatively like to do it. Not totally sure yet, but I'll definitely consider doing something(s).

Answer (score 1):

I'm in.  As I mentioned in Chat, if the final process is to use iMovie which we all have, then creating a dummie screencast with a snippet of video that we can replace as a form of template would be good.  Then we can do the (presumably) h.264 crunchdown for you and transfer a more sensibly sized file.

Comment: The iMovie template is definitely something I'll work on. The only issue is the little 'intro' card in the beginning, which is different for each screencast. Once I get the template done I'll post the details/instructions for the export settings that work well. Even after the template is made, I'll still be volunteering to edit and process the videos myself, in order to keep the barrier to entry nice and low.

Comment: You could make the "card" a blank card, and specify a font & size to use as a floating iMovie title just located over the blank area? Just type over the text and re-center to replace

Comment: Okay, updated the question with the iMovie template.